# textFieldDidBeginEditing using tags

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, nslog, nsexception

I'm running into a little issue with my textFieldDidBeginEditing method..

I'm trying to figure out which textfield is being called on to edit so I can decide if I want the view to move up or not to make the field visible.

Here is my method, I have commented some things out to try to find out where the error is:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
NSLog(@"This method is called");
//[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-120,320,568)];
if(sender.tag == _nameF.tag)
{
    NSLog(@"This if is called");
    //[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-120,320,568)];
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"Else called instead");
}

}
```

I see "This method is called" in the log, so I know the method is being called in the first place, but after that, I see this:

2013-07-23 12:27:18.654 SidebarDemo[2110:60b] -[NSConcreteNotification tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d7b8c0
2013-07-23 12:27:18.655 SidebarDemo[2110:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d7b8c0'

This leads me to believe that it is something with sender.tag, but I don't see anything wrong with my code, to my knowledge.

What could the issue be here? Is there another method I can use to find out what textfield is being edited?

Thanks.

Comment: how is _nameF being declared?

Comment: Is the error from `sender.tag` or `_nameF.tag`? Is this method being used by a `UITextFieldDelegate` or on behalf of a `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` notification?

Comment: It's being used on behalf of a UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification notification...

Comment: Can you not just do a raw pointer comparison?  if( sender == _nameF )

Comment: I have tried that, but then the if statement is not called, it goes to "else" for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are setting up the `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` notification to call your `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method, you need to change the method parameter. And to avoid confusion with the corresponding `UITextFieldDelegate` method, you should rename this method as well (which means you need to update the line of code that register the notification handler).

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditingHandler:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)notification.object;

    // It's OK to use == here since we really do want to compare pointer values
    if(textField == _nameF) {
        NSLog(@"This if is called");
        //[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-120,320,568)];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Else called instead");
    }
}
```

There is no need for tags since you have ivars for each text field.

BTW - why are you using notifications for this? Why not use the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods?

Comment: I just tried making the above changes in my code, but I get a similar error, but this time I don't believe the method is being called at all in the first place as "this method is called" is not in the log. Any ideas? Could you explain the uitextfield delegate way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: What's the error? Did you ensure that the method used when registering the notification matches the name of the new method name you used? Search the docs for `UITextFieldDelegate`. There is plenty of documentation and sample apps that show how to use it.

Comment: That was the issue, I forgot to change it. Thank you very much!